Build issue with MatX concerning initialisation of shared variables
I'm attempting to build and install MatX onto my Linux machine.
I'm following the instructions found here.
Except when I run the make -j command, I get the following trace:
/home/<me>/Documents/MatX/include/matx/kernels/channelize_poly.cuh(349): error: initializer not allowed for __shared__ variable 

/home/<me>/Documents/MatX/include/matx/kernels/channelize_poly.cuh(349): error: initializer not allowed for __shared__ variable 

/home/<me>/Documents/MatX/include/matx/kernels/channelize_poly.cuh(349): error: initializer not allowed for __shared__ variable 

/home/<me>/Documents/MatX/include/matx/kernels/channelize_poly.cuh(349): error: initializer not allowed for __shared__ variable 

/home/<me>/Documents/MatX/include/matx/kernels/channelize_poly.cuh(349): error: initializer not allowed for __shared__ variable 

/home/<me>/Documents/MatX/include/matx/kernels/channelize_poly.cuh(64): error: initializer not allowed for __shared__ variable 

Which is rather odd, since if you look at the offending lines in channelize_poly.cuh (see the source here), you see:
    // Lines 63 & 64
    const int SMEM_MAX_FILTER_TAPS = 128;
    __shared__ filter_t smem_filter[SMEM_MAX_FILTER_TAPS];

   // Lines 348 & 349
   // Pre-compute the DFT complex exponentials and store in shared memory
    __shared__ output_t smem_eij[NUM_CHAN][NUM_CHAN];

I.e. there is no supposed initialization of the shared variables.
The software I'm using:

CUDA 11.6
G++ 9.4.0
Ubuntu 20.04


https://github.com/NVIDIA/MatX/issues/669

So this is a known issue now. I've posted an issue on GH for this; see here. A fix looks to be on it's way.
